# Take only one record from many results when one columns contain same value in different rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, greatest-n-per-group

I have a my SQL results similar to below. I have been using rails and would like to have solution either in `SQL` or `Rails`

```
    id | name | addr | add_id
    -------------------------
    1 |   m  |   Q   |  15
    2 |   n  |   Q   |   3
    3 |   o  |   Q   |  37   
    4 |   f  |   R   |   8
    5 |   c  |   A   |   1
    6 |   r  |   M   |   6
    7 |   v  |   W   |  20
    8 |   z  |   T   |   4
```

What I was trying is to get only one row if there are multiple rows having common data in one of the column. For example, in the above results, I have `Id 1, 2 and 3` having common `addr` as `Q`. However, I would like to eliminate this behavior and want my results as below only taking one of the row's if there is repetition on one column. Anticipated results.

```
    id | name | addr | add_id
    -------------------------
    1 |   m  |   Q   |  15   
    4 |   f  |   R   |   8
    5 |   c  |   A   |   1
    6 |   r  |   M   |   6
    7 |   v  |   W   |  20
    8 |   z  |   T   |   4
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, `distinct on` comes handy for this:

```
select distinct on(addr) t.*
from mytable t
order by addr, id
```

If you do want to maintain the ordering by `id` in the resultset, you can wrap the query:

```
select *
from (select distinct on(addr) t.* from mytable t order by addr, id) t
order by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=32f869de54da6f4cb7ee4c8f734e050c)**:

```
id | name | addr | add_id
-: | :--- | :--- | -----:
 1 | m    | Q    |     15
 4 | f    | R    |      8
 5 | c    | A    |      1
 6 | r    | M    |      6
 7 | v    | W    |     20
 8 | z    | T    |      4
```

Comment: The above results are from a query. So, Ideally that query will be a subquery for the query you have posted.

Comment: @ZZzzZZzz: possibly, you can just add `distinct on` directly on your existing query. If that's not possible for some reason, then you can indeed use a subquery (ie replace `mytable ` in my query with your query).

Comment: When tried to put my query into your sample, I got the expected results except for the fact that the remaining duplicate records are shown at the bottom of the results instead of being removed.